# dplyr::end_with and case sensitivity

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to select all variables that ends with a capital `"T"`.

here is an example.

```
df <- data.frame(xt = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 yT = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                 zT = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))`

df %>% select(ends_with("T"))
```

results:

[image]

my question is how to make `ends_with` case sensitive.

Comment: all the select_helper functions have `ignore.case = TRUE`.  By changing to `ignore.case = FALSE`, should work

Comment: When in doubt, the docs show this default option: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyselect/versions/0.2.5/topics/select_helpers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to make use of the `ignore.case` argument:

```
df %>% select(ends_with("T", ignore.case = FALSE))

  yT zT
1  a  1
2  b  1
3  c  0
4  d  0
5  e  1
```